# Simple-flow example from the Java EE7 tutorial remembers values of previous flow

Tags: jsf, flow-scope

I'm just playing around with the simple-flow example from the Java EE7 tutorial and stumble on a problem.

Documentation:
[Java EE7 tutorial - Simple Flow](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-configure003.htm)

Example: tut-install/examples/web/jsf/simple-flow/

*I'm puzzled, because the flow remembers the data in the FlowScope after the return page.*

Example code from the manual:

```
src/main/webapp
    index.xhtml
    simple-flow-return.xhtml
    WEB_INF/
        web.xml
    simple-flow
        simple-flow-flow.xml
        simple-flow.xhtml
        simple-flow-page2.xhtml
```

Demo:

```
Enter flow
--> Value = test
--> Second Page - Value: test
--> Return
--> Value (should be empty): "" --> Correct!
--> Back to start
--> enter flow
--> Value: test (THIS VALUE IS REMEMBERED AND ALREADY FILLED IN!)
```

Why is this value remembered? I left to the return page and the value was empty, but now again remembered!

Has anybody the same problem with this example? (Tested on GlassFish and WildFly)

Comment: Is this definitely not a browser issue? Have you tried it once normal Chrome/FF, and then with your browser in private mode, or with a different browser altogether?

Comment: This is tested on Chrome on different development machines. We made some progress: this does not happen if we use a Managed bean, but for this simple tutorial, this should work with FlowScope without a bean, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made some progress:
Use the simple-flow example, from the tutorial, but with a Managed bean.